# What is the point of references in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll

Kind of silly question, but I still can't understand it.

Let's assume I have **A.exe** file and **B.dll** file.
**B.dll** is located in **../Somewhere/Debug/B.dll**.

I make a reference to this .dll from my **A.exe** project, but when I execute the **A.exe** it looks for the **B.dll** in the same directory, where **A.exe** is located. So why do I have to specify the path to **B.dll** (**../Somewhere/Debug/B.dll**) in my **A.exe** project if it does not actually use that?

I can build **A.exe** which references **../Somewhere/Debug/B.dll** with **CopyLocal = true**. Then, I can make changes to the **B.dll** (for example add a new Class) and build it. After that I am able to use that new Class in my **A.exe** project, but if I set **CopyLocal** on **B.dll** reference to **false** and build **A.exe**, I will face the **TypeLoadException** once I try to execute **A.exe**, since it uses the old version of **B.dll** which is located in the same folder where **A.exe** is located.

The same thing with strongly named assemblies which are located in the **GAC**. I reference this assembly (e.g. **../Test/My.dll**), but **CLR** still uses those which are located in the **GAC**.

Do references in **Visual Studio** play any role or they just serve for development purposes (like **IntelliSense**)?

Comment: The compiler needs to know which assemblies to link to, so it knows where to look for the classes you're using. Try getting rid of all the references and see if your project builds.

Answer (score 2):

References to assemblies (aka DLLs or EXEs) are used in two ways.  Let's take your example.  In `B.dll`, we have a class named `ClassB` which has a public default constructor and a public method (`ClassB.MethodB`) which takes a string and has a void return type.

In `A.exe`, the code instantiates an instance of a `ClassB` and calls `MethodB` on that instance:

```
var b = new ClassB();
b.MethodB("SomeString");
```

At compile time, the compiler needs to know about the existence of `ClassB`, as well as what its public methods/properties/etc. are.  In C++, that would be encoded in an H file.  In COM, it would be in a type library.  In .NET languages (VB, C#, etc.), that is exposed as *metadata* in the assembly itself.

So, when you compile the `A` project into `A.exe`, you need to provide the compiler with a reference to the `B.dll` assembly; that's how the compiler knows what a `B` is.  Note that there is nothing Visual Studio-specific in this; if you were to do this with `csc.exe` (the C# compiler), you'd still need to include the reference on the command line.

But, in addition to this, when `A.exe` runs, the runtime needs to load and JIT the `B.dll` assembly so that when the `b.MethodB("SomeString");` line of code in `A.exe` runs, it can call the right method in `B.dll`. (JIT means just-in-time compile -- which really isn't pertinent here)

As @waleedNaveed points out, the runtime behavior is different if the assembly is strongly named or not.  In particular, the runtime assembly search path for strongly-named assemblies starts with the GAC.

For non-strongly-named assemblies, the easiest place to find a referenced assembly is in the same folder as the currently executed assembly.  That's why you typically set "copy local" to true; it makes it *just work*.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will copy **B.dll** every time you compile your solution.

The objective is to allow you to target a dll somewhere outside of your solution. As an example, this dll can be maintained by another team. (but in this case, an internal nuGet package would be a better solution.)

Note that referencing dlls in your compilation folder is not a good idea, because the content of this folder can be cleaned between compilation. In that case you use a source control for your referenced dlls, the read-only flag on the dll in this folder can cause compilation issues.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your confusion regarding GAC. .NET framework starts by searching the dll(assembly) in the GAC (obviously if it is strongly named). If assembly is not found in the GAC, and if there is a .config file, then .NET framework searches the location in the configuration file, else .NET framework searches the assembly in the directory containing the executable (.exe). Even if the assembly is not found in the executable directory, then it gives the error.

Hope that answers your question and clears you confusion.